# How to access Event object inside javascript tag of Aspx page header content?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

I am trying to fire a event from script inside aspx page. To fire a event I am using `Event.observe()` method. In that line I am getting error like "Event is not an object". Please help me in this issue.

My code:

```
 function Submitkeyword() {
        obj = document.getElementById("select");//select is button id
        Event.observe(obj, 'change', function () {
            var e = document.getElementById("lookupvaluesDropdown");//lookupvaluesDropdown is dropdownlist id
            var valueddl = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;                
        });
        fireEvent(obj, 'submit'); 
        window.close(); //To close the popup window
    }
    function fireEvent(element, event) {
        if (document.createEventObject) {
            // dispatch for IE
            var evt = document.createEventObject();                 
            return element.fireEvent(event, evt);
        }
        else {
            // dispatch for firefox + others 
            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            evt.initEvent(event, true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable 
            return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To fire an event server side you need to do a postback or make an ajax call.  If you make an ajax call you could just call a web service that does whatever your event handler does.

Comment: @Ben Robinson Thanks form your response.Please explain me how to use web service...

Comment: OK, from your code it looks like you are talking about client side DOM events.

Comment: @Ben Robinson  Exactly I'm working on DOM events,Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Manse UK, is providing appropriate help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8913/discussion-between-murali-and-ben-robinson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Event.observe` requires the [Prototype JavaScript library](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe) loaded. If its not loaded and you try to use it you will get the error `"Event is not an object"`

You need to include that in your `<head>` as follows :

```
<script src="/path/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I didnt used. Please explain me how to add Prototype JavaScript library.

Comment: @Murali I think its pretty clear form my answer .... where did you get this code from ? do you even understand what its doing ? read the link I posted

Comment: I added this tag now I am not getting that error.But I am having some other problem I will post it.

Comment: How to get the present aspx page object? Thanks in advance.